# AngularJS (Restangular): wrap service method into timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, restangular

In basic $http i had such code (this is a service):

```
var getSomeData = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
      $http.get('...mylongurl', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .success(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
      });
    }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

and i transformed it into restangular so:

```
var getSomeData = function() {
  var user = Restangular.one('mylongurl');
  $timeout(function(){
    return user.get().then(function (response) {
      return response;
    }, function(error){
      return error;
    });
  }, 2000);
  return user;
};
```

and then in controller i use it so:

```
someService.getSomeData().then()...
```

but now with timeout i get: `someService.getSomeData().then is not a function`

Comment: you should use the same deferred it dosent have automatically  .then()

Comment: @Erez but restangular use promisses by default...

Comment: yes when you do user get 
but not the get some data function

Comment: @Erez example plz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `$timeout` returns a promise:

```
function getSomeData() {
  var user = Restangular.one('mylongurl');
  return $timeout(2000)
      .then(function(){
           return user.get();
       });
}
```

Older versions of angular may still require an empty function passed to the timeout `$timeout(function(){}, 2000)`, but if you are using a recent one you can just omit it altogether.